# One UILabel with two NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: swift

I was working with Xcode12 and swift5. My goal was to color some selected numbers (as illustrated) by a random background color in the multiplication table. The numbers on the rest of the table were replaced with apple emojis and yellow background color.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL0ar.png)

Here's my codes:

```
var content: String = ""
    for i in 1...9{
        for j in 1...9{
            if i == 9 || (j > 1 && j<5 && i+j == 10) || (i >= 5 && i == j)  {
                content += " " + "\(i*j)" + ""
                content += "\t"
                //create attributed string
                let myAttributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                    .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
                    .backgroundColor: UIColor(
                        red:   .random(in: 0...1),
                        green: .random(in: 0...1),
                        blue:  .random(in: 0...1),
                        alpha: 1.0
                     ),
                    .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
                ]
                let myAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: content, attributes: myAttributes)
                print(myAttrString)
                numberLabel.attributedText = myAttrString
            }else{
                content += " " + "" + ""
                content += "\t"
                //create attributed string
                let elseAttributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                    .kern: 5,
                    .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
                    .backgroundColor: UIColor.yellow,
                    .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
                ]
                let elseAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: content, attributes: elseAttributes)
                print(elseAttrString)
                numberLabel.attributedText = elseAttrString
            }
        }
        content += "\n"
    }
    
}
```

The output was colored by only one background color (random color) I was hoping to have apple strings come with yellow backgroundcolor while the selected numbers come with the other random color. Please help me get the desirable outcome. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmPkA.png)

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString(string: content, attributes: elseAttributes)` or `let myAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: content, attributes: myAttributes)`, it doesn't matter. You are override the WHOLE attributes with the last one called. Also, since you use `content`, you do not care about the previous attributedString, but the String only... That's why.

Comment: Instead of `var content: String` , use `let content: NSMutableAttributedString`, and append small `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration, you are appending stuff to a normal `String` variable - `content`, so you are not saving the attributes that you created previously. And by using `NSMutableAttributedString(string: content, attributes: myAttributes)`, you are applying those attributes to the whole `content`. This is why the attributes of the last iteration's is applied to the entire `content`.

To fix this, you should change `content` to an `NSMutableAttributedString`, and append `NSAttributedString`s to it. In each iteration, apply the attributes to only the *new* part of the string.

```
var content: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
for i in 1...9{
    for j in 1...9{
        let string: String
        let attributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key: Any]
        if i == 9 || (j > 1 && j<5 && i+j == 10) || (i >= 5 && i == j)  {
            string = " \(i*j)\t"
            attributes = [
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
                .backgroundColor: UIColor(
                    red:   .random(in: 0...1),
                    green: .random(in: 0...1),
                    blue:  .random(in: 0...1),
                    alpha: 1.0
                 ),
                .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
            ]
        }else{
            string = " \t"
            attributes = [
                .kern: 5,
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
                .backgroundColor: UIColor.yellow,
                .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
            ]
        }
        let attributedStringToAppend = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
        content.append(attributedStringToAppend)
    }
    content.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
}
```